# html video tag is not working for blob video file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video

html5 video tag is not working for the blob video file. Is there a way to convert blob file URL into mp4 in javascript? here is the link to the blob video file:

[vedio link](https://locate-me-fe.s3.amazonaws.com/69739216-715e-4c1c-98bf-dd9511febd2f-blob)

Comment: if you pass video link url in the src video attribute it's working fine.  [sandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-violet-7u8k1)

Comment: yes but if you see on the first load unless the full video does not play it makes controls disable and not showing the total time of the video